# Themes Not Loading in Wordpress 3.5.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just uploaded my site to Wordpress 3.5.1 via the CPanel Update and since then, themes stopped loading on my site. Even when I tried the default theme or a fresh install of the 3.5.1 WP Version it doesn't load.

I went to the WP Forum to see if I could find help but unfortunately No !!

I also tried various Browsers and even different Operating Systems ( Windows and Mac - I use Linux by default ).

Please check http://nvcrao.com - The StyleSheet loads but the theme doesn't come on.

Please help me get through this issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Sistla Abhishek !

Comment: What's the status of the same on localhost? And what's the status of the site without 3.5.1 upgrade?

Comment: I built it directly on the Live site. I wasn't at work for the past 2 weeks and hence the real time editing and stuff. Without the 3.5.1 Update it was working like a breeze. All my plugins were working great !! Now, it doesn't work even without them.

Comment: I could help if I had a bit more access to the website, but from what I can see is that there is a directory issue. Wordpress is unable to find images and scripts files at certain locations. Now this can occur if the files were mistakenly moved or some issue in database. Or could be as simple as a spelling mistake.

Comment: I've haven't edited any of the files in the WP directory recently and also, all the directories have the 755 permission to them.

Comment: If you have chrome browser press "ctrl+shift+I" to open developer tools at the bottom. In the Network tab (files highlighted in red) or in console tab "marked 'Not Found'" you will see the files which are not being loaded. Maybe that can give you an idea what might be the issue.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik The Images are not loading. But at the same time, there is no Style that is loading. I want the styles back on first. Any way to Troubleshoot the same ? Please let me know.

Comment: If you can see in the console that even the stylesheet that has the extension of .css is not being loaded. I cant really help in that as I don't have much access. If you want you can get to me on skype (same id as here). But all I can tell you at the moment is that files are not being loaded but not sure as to why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23456/discussion-between-svabhishek-and-jehanzeb-malik)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your stylesheets and your images are missing. For example, your theme's `style.css` returns not found: http://nvcrao.com/wp-content/themes/panoramica/style.css

Can you connect to your site via FTP or SFTP and check your `/wp-content/uploads/` and `/wp-content/themes/` directories? You may just need to reupload your theme (with its assets).

Comment: Ryan, I just did that but they still are missing.

Comment: What did you see in those directories?

Comment: I had all the files but they aren't loading. They are all re uploaded and I gave them the 755 permission too !!

Comment: I just Activated the default Wordpress theme - Twenty Twelve but that doesn't seem to load the styles or images.

Comment: Hm... Are you 100% positive you're in the right directory? I am sure you have checked, but I can't think of anything else. Do you have the site on localhost or a staging server?

Comment: Yes, I have it backed up on the local server now. I was just testing the backed up copy of my site. It is working fine !!! But not able to load it on the server !!!